# Flask-restful: How to only response to requests come with ('Accept':'application/json')?

Tags: python, json, api, rest, flask

I have a json api APP, working well.Now I want it only accept and response json, not response to text/html request. 
App looks like this:

```
class Books(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return json.dumps(data)
```

Someone can help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a preprocessing request handler to reject all request with the wrong MimeType. There is a property of the `Request` object (not documented tought, but present at least on Flask 0.10) named `is_json`

Given your Flask app is called application, you could use something like :

```
from flask import request, abort, jsonify

@application.before_request
def only_json():
    if not request.is_json: 
        abort(400)  # or any custom BadRequest message
```

I would also use the Flask `jsonify` function to build your reponse, it will ensure that the response is well formatted in json, and also sets the right headers.

```
class Books(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: Thank you @afrancais, but how to do this on a upper level , if I have a tons of endpoints to handle?

Comment: @longnight: The `before_request`  decorator is applied on all Flask application endpoints. If you want to apply this filter on only a part of your endpoints, you could create a `Blueprint` instance and applying the `before_request` decorator on the blueprint instead of the application. For the return value, there is no magic way. Yes, there is a `after_request` decorator, but when it is called, the Response has already been built. I see two ways to force json responses : use a decorator applyable on your endpoints , or override the `make_reponse` method of the Flask class to force jsonify.

Comment: I stand corrected, you are apparently using the `Flask-restful` extension, which does generated JSON response by default (by overriding the make_response method). So you should not have to dump the results of the request in json, it is made automatically by  the framework you're using.

Comment: Yes , I'm using ```Flask-restful```, what I wanna do is to abort those None claiming ```Accept: application/json``` request, your first solution ```app.before_request``` already point out the right way, thanks again :)

Comment: I believe `is_json` was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/pallets/flask/commit/e5bba9deb5c9ab9c66bea5c17e96741777fe46ab). This meants, that it is not available in Flask 0.10.1